# How do you force wx.ListCtrl scroll bars to auto-lock to the bottom so that the most recent data is shown in the window?

Tags: python, wxpython

As new data comes into my wx.ListCtrl the window fills up and scroll bars appear.  What I want to do is to have the most current data (at the bottom of the list) displayed on the windows.  My first idea was a way to force the wx.ListCtrl scroll bars to default to the bottom of the window.  If there is another/better way to do this I am all ears.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After you add the new items, you should be able to use

```
self.EnsureVisible(self.GetItemCount() - 1)
```

to pin the scrollbar to the bottom.

Comment: `self.EnsureVisible(self.GetItemCount() - 1 if self.GetItemCount() > 0 else 0)` It seems, that `self.EnsureVisible(-1)` works fine, but just in case...